# How to close related videos Dailymotion in embed iframe?

Tags: iframe, embed, dailymotion-api

[image]

I don't wanna see this related videos end of the videos.I saw the `endscreen-enabled` configuration but it's not working anymore i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't manage queue directly via the player IFrame, you need to create a custom player configuration in your [partner space](https://www.dailymotion.com/partner/embed/players) (or directly using [REST API](https://developer.dailymotion.com/api/#player)) and disable queue on it, then use this specific player to launch the video as described in [our documentation](https://developer.dailymotion.com/player/#player-iframe-embed)